# Wifi adapter freezes laptop when it connects (Ubuntu Studio 16.10) but works fine when booted in Ubuntu 16.10 live usb

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

Realtek RTL8188CU based wifi adapter locks up my Ubuntu Studio 16.10 laptop (Lenovo G400) when connecting to the internet and CapsLock and ScrollLock start blinking, forcing a hard restart.  Created a live USB of Ubuntu 16.10 and same wifi adapter works perfectly.  What's up with that?

Comment: I suggest you install all the updates using an alternative internet connection. Reboot and try again.